# How to check device logs for alarms?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, alarm

I upgraded my iPhone 6S to iOS 11 this year, and now the alarm clock occasionally doesn't ring even I silent mode is turned off, the ringer volume is up and I have enough battery.

Of course, this is just a guess. Maybe I didn't hear the alarm?

Nope, I let the alarm ring continuously and I saw a notification on the screen. (on some forums it says it rings for about 15 min and then it shows this notification).

Is there any way to check the logs for the alarm app? I checked out Xcode's `Devices and Simulators`, but I can only see crashes.